# single row output with multiple columns in mysql, can i populate those columns in multiple rows

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    count(case when a.Rank between 0 and  3000 then a.ProductId end ) as SKUsNotAvailable,
    count(case when a.Rank between 3001 and  5000 then a.ProductId end ) as SKUsNotAvailable,
    count(case when a.Rank between 5001 and  10000 then a.ProductId end ) as SKUsNotAvailable,
    count(case when a.SOH<a.ReserveQty and a.Rank between 0 and  3000 then a.ProductID end) as SKUslessthanResQty,
    count(case when a.SOH<a.ReserveQty and a.Rank between 3001 and 5000 then a.ProductID end) as SKUslessthanResQty,
    count(case when a.SOH<a.ReserveQty and a.Rank between 5001 and  10000 then a.ProductID end) as SKUslessthanResQty
FROM
    pos_summary.tbl_city_product_rank_soh_resqty a
    inner join pos.tbl_store b
```

```
SKUsNotAvailable SKUsNotAvailable SKUsNotAvailable SKUslessthanResQty SKUslessthanResQty SKUslessthanResQty
27               35               159              22                 30                 124
```

"i am getting this output in a single row how can i get it in two column" like

```
SKUsNotAvailable    SKUslessthanResQty
27                   22
35                   30
159                  124
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like

```
SELECT count(a.ProductId) as SKUsNotAvailable,
       count(case when a.SOH<a.ReserveQty then a.ProductID end) as SKUslessthanResQty,
FROM pos_summary.tbl_city_product_rank_soh_resqty a
/* INNER JOIN pos.tbl_store b ON ?????? */
CROSS JOIN pos.tbl_store b
WHERE a.Rank between 0 and  10000
GROUP BY a.Rank between 0 and  3000, 
         a.Rank between 3001 and  5000
```

Answer (score 0):

"we can get like this also"

```
SELECT
 (case
   when a.Rank between 1 and 3000 then '1-3000'
   when a.Rank between 3001 and 5000 then '3001-5000' 
   when a.Rank between 5001 and 10000 then '5001-10000' end) as Ranks,
    count(case when a.Category= 'Z' then a.ProductId end) as SKUsNotAvailable,
    sum(case when a.Category='Z' then c.AvgSaleValue else 0 end) as LossSaleValue,
    count(case when a.Category= 'R' then a.ProductID end) as SKUslessthanResQty,
    sum(case when a.Category='R' then c.AvgSaleValue else 0 end) as LossSaleValue_ResQty
FROM
    pos_summary.tbl_city_product_rank_soh_resqty a
    inner join pos_summary.tbl_store b on a.StoreId = b.StoreID and b.Region_2 = 'TG'
    inner join pos_summary.tbl_city_sku_avg_sale_detail c on a.ProductID=c.ProductID and a.City=c.City
WHERE
    a.Rank between 0 and 10000
group by
 Ranks;
```